# How would I prevent someone from adding one of the same characters into a textbox in C#?

Tags: c#, calculator, point

Alright, here's the scenario. I'm building a calculator and I want to prevent the user (of the calculator) from being able to add more than one point (.), because obviously 1.2.1 isn't a real number, so how would I make it so only one point could be added to the text box they're typing into?

Comment: WinForms? ASP.Net? Silverlight? WPF? MonoTouch? XNA?

Comment: You have not answered my question.  **What UI framework are you using?**  Also, it's called C#.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use a MaskedEdit box which is eaxctly for this kind of purpose

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4cw90af%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Nice thought, I always forget about that one

Comment: Please revisit comment "You have not answered my question. What UI framework are you using? Also, it's called C#" first :)

Answer (score 1):

You could listen for TextChanged events, as Poma points out, and look at what is in the input box. You then have (basically) two choices:

1. Fix the input live (ie. reset the text so there is no error
2. Give some visual feedback to indicate that something is wrong

I typically go with option 2, to indicate the error I:

1. Disable any input options (ie. OK buttons)
2. Change the background color of the text field to some light shade of red

Be careful if you go with option 1 because changing the text programtically will also generate text changed events. One solution is to set a boolean flag, ie.

```
private bool changingText = false;

private void myTextBox_textChanged(...)
{
   if(changingText)
      return;

   fixErrors();
}

private void fixErrors()
{
    // Before changing myTextBox.Text, set the flag
   changingText = true;
   myTextBox.Text = ...
   changingText = false;
}
```

There are other options too, those are just the most common.

Edit:

Another, potentially better, solution is to handle the OnKeyDown for the text box, if the key isn't something you want - simply set the event's Handled property to true. Either way will work.

-- Dan

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextChanged` event to validate user input

Comment: That won't allow you to reject characters.

Comment: How would I use that to prevent the user from entering the same character of full stop/point (.) twice?